# EXCEL: How to import Data from Text File

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

I want to import this text file into excel: ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/data/trace_gases/co2/flask/surface/co2_mlo_surface-flask_1_ccgg_event.txt

Every time I import it it puts everything in one column. Someone please help me organize this data into excel. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does you import this file using the master or by VBA code? Does the header lines count can vary?

Comment: refer to this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions in the Microsoft article
[Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857),
and pay attention to:

- Use *Data tab > External Data group > From Text > Import Text File*
- Set *Original data type* to Delimited
- Set *Start import at row* to 71
- In the next step, set *Delimiters* to Space (you may also leave Tab),
  leaving *Treat consecutive delimiters as one* as checked
- In the next step, leave *Column data format* as General,
  click *Advanced* and uncheck
  *Trailing minus*, click OK
- Click Finish
- In the next step, choose *Existing worksheet*, leave `=$A$1` if you don't
  wish a columns header or change to `=$A$2` if you you want a header
- Click OK
- To add the header, select in the file the line starting the selection from
  `sample_site_code sample_year sample_month sample_day sample_hour ...`
- Click the cell A1
- In the Home tab, click the down-arrow next to Paste and choose
  *Use text import wizard*
- Follow the same steps as above to import into `=$A$1`

Answer (score 0):

As this is neither a comma separated nor a tab separated data, just values separated by multiple spaces, fields need to be defined by you manually.

This adds to what harry has defined above

[image: define fields by clicking at lines]

Scroll down until you can see this actual data, then click at the end of each data point so that a line appears like this, if the click was not at the right place, you will be able to move line to left right by clicking and dragging it.

If you so wish you can even combine three fields so that entire date (1969 08 20) comes in a single cell and you can later on make them to your date format.

once you have drawn all lines till the right end of data, go ahead as is described above.

leading space will automatically be removed from each imported data.

As headers are of different width, those will not come correctly, so you can delete the top most line that has randomly broken headers.